# replicate font size and font family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to replicate the same font style, size and overall look of text as on this page: https://www.alessandro-international.com/b2b_de_de/hand-nagelpflege/
And I am interested only on one element (`.subcat-descrition p`)

It seemed for me that I apply the same font-size and font-style, however, I get different result. You can see two images of text. The first one is desired one. The second is what I get. Is it font problem?

[image: Original picture with font]

[image: Try to replicate]

And I am interested in `subcat-descrition > p` element style here.

If I look in Chrome debugger I can see that `subcat-descrition > p` has

**CSS:**

```
.subcat-descrition p {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    min-height: 56px;
}

font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridfull subcats">
    <a href="https://www.alessandro-international.com/b2b_de_de/hand-nagelpflege/professional-manicure/">
        <img ... />
        <h3 class="cat-heading">Professional Manicure</h3>
        <span class="subcat-descrition"><p>Die Profi-Nagelpflegeserie für Zuhause: Die in Top Studios erprobten Produkte unserer Professional Manicure Serie werden einzeln oder in Kombination angewendet. Reinigung, Pflege, Kürzen und Formen zur optimalen Vorbereitung auf die Maniküre…</p></span>
```

However, when I try to replicate it on another website, I get absolutely another look of element: http://www.alessandro.lv/categories/nagu-un-roku-kopsana/
And element is `subcategory-description`.

**CSS**

```
.subcategory-description {
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    min-height: 56px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: In their (or your) code, are there any other styles that may be overriding the styles you are showing?

Comment: The paragraphs in the links look the same to me